# How to calculate percentage of column in table between two dates

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query for displaying percentage of canvas column,this query selects all the rows and calculates the percentage,

```
SELECT ma.canvas, COUNT(1) AS total, COUNT(1) / t.cnt * 100 AS `percentage` FROM tbl_mytable ma  CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM tbl_mytable ) t  group by ma.canvas
```

I want to calculate percentage for between two dates, I have a column in my table called ptime which stores the time.

I have tried

```
SELECT ma.canvas,ma.ptime, COUNT(1) AS total, COUNT(1) / t.cnt * 100 AS `percentage` FROM tbl_mytable ma CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM tbl_mytable ) t on ptime>='01-13-2017' and ptime<='01-15-2017' group by ma.canvas
```

as well as

```
SELECT ma.canvas,ma.ptime, COUNT(1) AS total, COUNT(1) / t.cnt * 100 AS `percentage` FROM tbl_mytable ma CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM tbl_mytable ) t where ptime>='01-13-2017' and ptime<='01-15-2017' group by ma.canvas
```

but all shows the empty table

Please help solve this problem

Comment: could you please show your table structure?

Comment: @Pirate updated

Comment: Run this query and check how many records you are getting,SELECT * FROM tbl_mytable where ptime>='01-13-2017' and ptime<='01-15-2017'

Comment: What exactly do you want to count? In `COUNT()` you need to put a column in between, and not a 1.. or maybe im getting something wrong here.

Comment: @Pirate  Thanks bro it's because time stored in the format 2017-01-17 but i am querying it in the different format '01-15-2017'. is there anyway to solve this problem in mysql?

Comment: your welcome, someone give the answer. Try that.

Comment: Just fix the date. Simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's because time stored in the format 2017-01-17 but i am querying it in the different format 01-15-2017

Use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in where clause.

```
SELECT 
    ma.canvas,
    ma.ptime, 
    COUNT(1) AS total, 
    COUNT(1) / t.cnt * 100 AS `percentage` 
FROM tbl_mytable ma 
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM tbl_mytable 
) t 
WHERE ptime >= STR_TO_DATE('01-13-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')
and ptime <= STR_TO_DATE('01-15-2017', '%d-%m-%Y') 
group by ma.canvas
```

Note that the result `ma.ptime` is still in the format of `%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s`. You can use the [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format your results.